# Loop execution speed control

Tags: java, loops

Is there a way to control the speed of execution of a loop ? 
I have a simulation  that runs in a loop of 30000 steps. I want to visualise whats happening in that loop and if possible control the speed of execution while its running. Any ideas how i could do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `Thread.sleep()` statement inside the loop. Beware though that you have to handle the exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {

    ...

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // do something with e
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to note that if you need a specific speed you need to measure execution time and sleep for the delta.

Comment: I guess i can change the sleep time while the program is running .For example from a button on a GUI. Is that correct ?

Comment: But how will you know within the loop execution if the program is writing a button on the GUI?

Comment: Didnt quite understand that . Ill try to have the latency value saved in a field and that field would change from GUI. Ill have to work on it for now.

Comment: Oh! You can do that. But you'll have to have the loop read the value of latency from a different place. Have you looked at [JMX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html)?

Comment: Havent seen that before .Ill check that now .Thanks !

Comment: It's quite cool. Basically by running the JMX console, you'll get a UI with which you can change attributes of monitored classes at runtime. All you need to do is adhere to the JavaBean conventions and make your class implement an interface. Try it.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a [`sleep`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)  to the loop to pause each iteration.

A better question though, is how are you visualizing this? I'm guessing you're watching the text flash by on the console... if that's the case you might want to consider outputting to files rather than the screen. That way you can read through the output at your leisure and you don't have to add artificial slowdowns to the program.

...but if by "visualise" it's an actual GUI thing, then yeah, the sleep might be better.

Comment: Even better than outputting text to a file is using an IDE with a debugger - so you can check variables, etc, at each step. Eclipse, for example.

Comment: @rib.usa: Good point! For 30k iterations it's hard to say if OP is looking for general pattern, or debugging a specific error. But yeah, I agree OP should look into a visual debugger too.

Comment: Yes i am planning to output the results in a graph and graph would change while program is running.

Comment: @latusaki: In that case, could you write your output to a file then use a different program to load that file and create a static graph? Does the graph need to be updated in real time or is creating one after the execution OK?

Comment: Its part of the extra work so ill try to update the graph in realtime. Thought it will look nice .if that doesnt work ill just make a graph after execution.

Comment: @latuski: If you're updating the graph in real-time and you want to slow it down, then `sleep()` is the answer (as originally stated).

Answer (score 1):

you can put inside your loop `Thread.sleep(latency);` where latency is in millis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 'Thread.sleep()' as the other guys said. But to "know" what happens in the loop I think you'd better **debug** it.. I think the worst case is to Print everything on the screen (wouldn't be so bad outside a loop, but considering 50+ loops it becomes impracticable.