# Controlling loop excecution speed in java - Android

Tags: java, android, loops, imageview, thread-sleep

I know that this is a very small question. But I can't figure out the reason for this. In my program I run a loop 50 times. Inside the loop I generate a random integer 0 to 5 and load an image(a dice image) to a imageView. So imageView should change rapidly and I should be able to see some visual like dice value is changing rapidly.

But I couldn't see any such change in imageView and at end of the loop, imageView changes at once.I mean if initial dice value is 2 it remains in two until loop finishes and then imageView suddenly change to 5 or some value like that.

I realized that I can't see a change in dice imageView since loop is executing very fast. Then after going through  [Loop execution speed control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261943/loop-execution-speed-control) I put Thread.sleep method but still there is not a change.

This is my code:

```
ImageView dice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewrollingdiceOne);
for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println("Random Value"+randomNum);
        dice.setImageResource(images[randomNum]);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ex called");
        }
    }
```

Can somebody explain the reason for this? I'm not getting any error in logcat.

this is logcat:

```
02-05 18:38:38.515: D/OpenGLRenderer(27058): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-05 18:38:42.179: D/TextLayoutCache(27455): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
02-05 18:38:42.239: D/libEGL(27455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-05 18:38:42.239: D/libEGL(27455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-05 18:38:42.249: D/libEGL(27455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-05 18:38:42.249: D/libEGL(27455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-05 18:38:42.279: D/OpenGLRenderer(27455): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 18:38:50.146: D/OpenGLRenderer(27455): Flushing caches (mode 0)
02-05 18:38:52.148: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:38:52.348: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:52.579: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
02-05 18:38:52.789: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:53.029: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
02-05 18:38:53.219: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:53.420: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:53.620: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:53.830: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:53.870: D/dalvikvm(27455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1035K, 11% free 9856K/10979K, paused 12ms+2ms
02-05 18:38:54.070: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:54.300: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:54.501: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:54.701: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:54.931: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:55.131: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1 
02-05 18:38:55.331: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:55.532: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:55.732: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:55.942: I/System.out(27455): Random Value3
02-05 18:38:56.162: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:38:56.362: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:56.563: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:56.763: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:38:56.973: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
02-05 18:38:57.193: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:57.393: I/System.out(27455): Random Value3
02-05 18:38:57.594: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:57.794: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:38:58.004: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:38:58.204: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0 
02-05 18:38:58.404: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:58.605: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:38:58.805: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:59.005: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:38:59.215: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
02-05 18:38:59.415: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:38:59.616: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
02-05 18:38:59.816: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:39:00.016: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:39:00.216: I/System.out(27455): Random Value3
02-05 18:39:00.416: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:39:00.617: I/System.out(27455): Random Value4
02-05 18:39:00.817: I/System.out(27455): Random Value1
02-05 18:39:01.027: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:39:01.227: I/System.out(27455): Random Value3
02-05 18:39:01.427: I/System.out(27455): Random Value3
02-05 18:39:01.628: I/System.out(27455): Random Value5
02-05 18:39:01.828: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2 
02-05 18:39:02.028: I/System.out(27455): Random Value0
02-05 18:39:02.228: I/System.out(27455): Random Value2
```

Comment: How about drawing Bitmaps on a SurfaceView Canvas instead?

Comment: Not exactly the most efficient method, from docs: `This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup.`

Comment: Most likely you are tying up the GUI thread preventing it from doing anything else, like displaying your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. The other answer also was very useful.

I used following inside the run method.

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
```

and it worked. This is the full answer, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733592/changing-images-in-a-loop-android?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(6);
    dice.setImageResource(images[randomNum]);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
 }, 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of sleeping Main UI thread by using `Thread.sleep` create a Thread or use Handler for make wait to change images in ImageView as:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

            // put your code here to change image in ImageView...

       }
     }, 200);
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. I don't know whether I'm doing it in correct way. I wrote the code again as following.

`for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     ImageView dice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewrollingdiceOne);
     int randomNum = random.nextInt(6);
     System.out.println("Random Value" + randomNum);
     dice.setImageResource(images[randomNum]);
    }
   }, 1000);` 

but loop executes in very fast.there cannot see a delay.it prints all 50 values within a second. Am I doing it correct way?

Comment: @S.Basnagoda : no need to use for loop just remove it

Comment: remove for loop? I want to see a some kind of visual.I mean I want to see that dice images are changing rapidly. If I remove for loop it will change imageView just one time. isn't it? 
thanks ρяσѕρєя K.

Comment: @S.Basnagoda : but your current logic is not good you can it as `public static int i=0;
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
 public void run() { 
 ImageView dice = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewrollingdiceOne); 
 int randomNum = random.nextInt(6); 
         
 System.out.println("Random Value" + randomNum); 
       if(i<images.size()){
  dice.setImageResource(i); 
          i++;
        }
        else{
           i=0;
         }
 } 
}, 1000);
`

Comment: @  ρяσѕρєя K : There was not a crashing problem in my app. I'm not clear what you are saying.